# System of linear equations in 4 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

The system is as follows: 5$x_1$ -6$x_2$ +3$x_3$ +4$x_4$ =4, -1$x_1$ +1$x_2$ +2$x_3$ +2$x_4$=2 , 4$x_1$ -5$x_2$ + 5$x_3$ +6$x_4$=6, -3$x_1$ +3$x_2$ +6$x_3$ +6$x_4$ =6. I have tried this multiple times and I am always left with 2 equations: 5$x_1$ -6$x_2$ +3$x_3$ +4$x_4$ =4 and  -1$x_1$ +1$x_2$ +2$x_3$ +2$x_4$=2. Where do I go from here/what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I've edited it. Made a mistake in typing it out.

Comment: how did you arrive at that?

Comment: can you please explain the operations you used?

Comment: @user140161 Look up "Gaussian Elimination", and "Reduced Row Echelon Form".